# Similar functionality of bootstrap forms-controls-static in Semantic-ui

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-ui

Is there a class in [Semantic-UI](http://Semantic-UI.com) that's similar to `forms-controls-static` class in bootstrap which places plain text next to a form label within a form as it's described in the link and images below:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static

**Full Width**:

[image: Wide]

---

**Resized**:

[image: Resized]

---

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The question is old, but as I also needed this function and I did not find a native solution so I created a css to solve.

```
.field .ui.static {
  min-height: 34px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

And use

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui labeled input">
    <div class="ui label">
      Name:
    </div>
    <p class="ui static">{{name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that is an ancient question, but regarding documentation form-control-static has been migrated to read only input with class form-control-plaintext

```
 <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com">
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for inline fields.

## Screenshot

[image: Semantic UI Inline Field]

## Code

```
<div class="ui form">
  <div class="inline field">
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
  </div>
</div>
```

## Link

http://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html#inline

Comment: The point is to display the value of "Last Name" in plain text other than read-only textbox.